# useParams() return undefined, but param exists in the destination URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

I have a full **list of items** that are called "Commandes" (PS: the app is in french) and they are displayed in a table with a column for each row that should redirect me to another component responsible for showing more details about the row I redirected from, so in order to do that of course I ought to use useParams hook in order to send the id of the object (the id here in this case is referred to as "No"),
Then I will send the id to a back-end endpoint that will get the rest of the object's data,
my problem is that I have the id ("No") sent from the origin component correctly and with the correct Route configuration it get displayed in the URL as a param when I redirect but when I log the "No" in the destination component it says **Undefined**,
please find below the code snippets explained:

1. **This the the first component where I initially send the "No" from the full list and redirect to the details component:**

```
<td>
    <IconButton
    variant="outlined"
    color="error"
    style={{ color: "#02047a" }}
    onClick={() => handleDetailsClick(ligne.No)}>
    <LoupeOutlinedIcon />
    </IconButton>
</td>
```

**2- this is the function that handle the button click and redirects me to the new component URL with the No as a param**

```
    const history = useHistory();
    const handleDetailsClick = (No) => {  
      history.push(`/components/blocks/Hero/DetailsCommande/${No}`);
    };
```

**3- This is my param route configuration, when I redirect to it the No is well present in the URL and I tested with different objects and the redirection works with the param in it, please note that my route config is in a separate file and I call that file in my app.js to render the routes whenever I call one since I have many different routes (as far as it goes the route works fine with the No in it when I redirect):**

```
DetailsCommande: {
          name: "Details commandes",
          component: DetailsCommande,
          url: "/components/blocks/Hero/DetailsCommande/:No",
        },
```

**3- And this is the function that should handle the const that I set from useParams and call a back-end API to do the rest of the work, but for now when I log the param right after calling the useParams hook I get UNDEFINED so its not extracting it from the URL to begin with:**

```
const { No } = useParams();
console.log(No);

const fetchCommandeData = async (paramOrderNo) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("/commande/details", {
      params: { No: paramOrderNo },
    });
    const responseLigne = await axios.get("/commande/getLignes", {
      params: { cmdNo: paramOrderNo },
    });

    setCommandeData(response.data); // Store the fetched commande response data
    setLigneCommandeData(responseLigne.data); // Store the fetched lignes response data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (No) {
    fetchCommandeData(No);
  }
}, [No]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From here i can't see any mistake, maybe make sure the "No" value is define.

```
const history = useHistory();
const handleDetailsClick = (No) => {  
    // add console.log(No)
    history.push(`/components/blocks/Hero/DetailsCommande/${No}`);
};
```